# How to select .NET 4.5.2 as a target framework in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-4.5.2

I have installed [.NET Framework 4.5.2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42642) on Windows 8.1. But in Visual Studio 2013 I do not see the .NET Framework 4.5.2 option (see screenshot). How do I target my project for .NET 4.5.2?

[image]

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You need to install the [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637)

This contains the following components (emphasis added by me):

> - .NET Framework 4.5.2
> - **.NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack: Contains the reference assemblies needed to build apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.2**
> - .NET Framework 4.5.2 Language Packs
> - .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi-Targeting Pack Language Packs: Contains the IntelliSense files to display help while building apps that target
>   the .NET Framework 4.5.2 through Visual Studio and third party IDEs.

Comment: Make sure you use the download package (as per the link), rather than the web installer.  The latter will not install the multi-targeting pack--even if you have Visual Studio 2013 installed.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I can't understand why, and how to solve it.

This is my VS asset:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51209

Any clue ?

Comment: Bizarre, I reinstalled it and now it works... thanks anyway :)

Comment: All my projects show as incompatible even after installing from that link. Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: @jlg have you tried to restart your machine? Sometimes the install needs an extra restart...

Comment: Yeah, I just did. They still show up as incompatible.

Comment: It looks like it is because of Windows 8. Apparently I'm supposed to run Visual Studio as administrator to get it to work. I just got the new OS yesterday and it's already making me want to rip my hair out!

Comment: Do I need the multilinual packages?

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio before it picked up on 4.5.2.  Make sure you do that after installing the Multi-Targeting pack.

Comment: Incidentally, this same pattern repeats for the issue when trying to target 4.6.1

Comment: @JosephStyons, I would like to suggest you to install the 'Developer Pack' and not the 'runtime' version.

Comment: I have this issue on VS2017 on Windows 10, but the provided link doesn't specify Windows 10. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The point was that I have installed DevPack only for my language.

NDP462-DevPack-KB3151934-RUS.exe

as the result the appropriate folder here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework
```

contained only one folder "ru", while the folder 4.6.1 was full of files.

In the end, installing

NDP462-DevPack-KB3151934-ENU.exe

solved the problem.