# Configuring .NET Framework 4.5.2 in IIS 8.0

Tags: iis-8, .net-4.5.2

In my Windows Server 2012, I have installed .NET Framework 4.5.2, but it is not listing in IIS when I tried to change one application pool's .NET Framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The application pool should be set to .net 4.0, that includes all updates like 4.5.1 and 4.5.2

All other settings are through config, for example:

```
  <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Hi eric, so i will be selecting .net framework v4.0.30319 in the iis 8.0 application pool and config file as follows, `<system.web> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" /> <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" /> </system.web>` Am I missing something here ? Any other changes in IIS ?

Comment: Not for IIS, for your web application maybe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617900/how-to-select-net-4-5-2-as-a-target-framework-in-visual-studio

Comment: And after doing the above changes how can I be sure whether my application is using .net framework 4.5.2 only ?  Is there a way to check ? :)

Comment: not really, check for features, not for versions: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx

Answer (score 0):

install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Developer Pack https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637