# Cannot Target .Net 4.5.2 in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-8.5

I've got a new site that I'm creating in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Using the info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28562006/configuring-net-framework-4-5-2-in-iis-8-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559372/how-to-set-net-framework-4-5-version-in-iis-7-application-pool?rq=1) I was still getting an error trying to use interpolated strings.

From my error screenshot below, it appears to be still targeting the .NET v4.0 framework? I have checked and .NET 4.5.2 is definitely installed on the server.

Would greatly appreciate any help!

[image: Error]
[image: Advanced Settings App Pool]
[image: Web.Config]

Comment: `.NET 4.5` means `.NET >= 4.5`, so that's not the problem

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes but see the first screenshot, the version is .NET 4.0 ??

Comment: That's the CLR version. `4.0` = `.NET >= 4.0`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto OK so what do you suggest the issue is?

Comment: I assume you've deleted everything from your IIS site directory and republished a clean build of your app?

Comment: Not sure from where did you get this project. But the default templates from Visual Studio should include Roslyn as a dependency, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/05/12/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/, which should resolve the issue at runtime. If you don't bundle Roslyn, then the legacy compiler from .NET Framework installation would be used, which has no idea what C# 6 is, like I blogged in https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-the-so-many-c-compilers-f3a85500707c