# Update MVC from 4.0 to 5.2 - Could not install package

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to update my project from MVC 4.0 to 5.2. But As soon I do that I get an error message:

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'. You are trying to install this packag
e into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly referen
ces or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

How can I Solve this issue? And What does this mean?

Comment: MVC 5.2 is ASP.net 4.5, not ASP.net 4.0

Comment: So I should update the project to asp.net 4.5 first?

Comment: Do you know the Nuget Command for that?

Comment: it's not a NuGet Command.   you change the framework the project is targeting in the project properties.

Comment: Are you using Visual studio 2013?

Comment: Okej, is there any tutorial website where I can read more about how to update the ASP.NET Framework?

Comment: are you following the steps from http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2?

Comment: Yes, Im using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: This answer might help you with installation of 4.5 then http://stackoverflow.com/a/23618042/1370442

Comment: If I run Update-Package in nuget will it update the ASP.NET? or Just the MVC?

Comment: as I already said once, you don't update ASP.NET from NuGet.

Comment: But you sent me a link. With the command "Update-Package". And it updates all the packages using NuGet. But I dont think it updates the ASP.NET.

Comment: @Arif You set the framework version using `Project / *your project name* Properties / Target framework`, within Visual Studio. You don't change it via NuGet, which is simply a package manager.