# ASP.NET MVC C# Web Section Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am starting to study ASP.NET MVC but now I see that I don't have the whole "web section" when I open new project. Before I studied pure C# (Console Applications) so I didn't really need it and I haven't noticed that it doesn't exist in my Visual Studio.

[image]

So I can't make a new MVC project... How can I add it? Is there a way of adding it without reinstalling the Visual Studio? PS: I use Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Try changing the framework version in the dropdown. .NET Framework 3.5 is only for legacy applications - you should be using .NET Framework 4.5+ for new applications. It should also change what you see in the list of options.

Comment: @NightOwl888 how can i change it to 4.5+ ? I mean I only have 2.0, 3.0, 3.50 and <More Frameworks...> option. Should I click the "More Frameworks" option?

Comment: @dipper check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27469861/619131

Comment: @AliSheikhNezami i saw it... but it says how to fix it with reinstalling the Visual Studio

Comment: @dipper you most do it to fix your problem dude !

Comment: @dipper - you can install more frameworks by installing the [developer pack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23618042/181087) for the corresponding version number. I am not sure if that will fix your original issue, though - you may need to do a "repair" on Visual Studio 2015 Community in order to install that option - and to do that you need to run the installer for it again.

Comment: @NightOwl888 ok for now i installed the dev pack and tried to modify my Microsoft Visual Studio Community with Updates from the control panel. But the Microsoft Web Developer Tools was already checked... Anyway trying to do a "repair" now

Comment: @NightOwl888 still dont have it...

Comment: You might want to go through the [prerequisites](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f18e46ae-f6ae-4e34-b0be-5fe7198d7026/prerequisites-to-install-visual-studio-2015?forum=winservergen) and make sure you have them all installed. Also, once you have done that, it may be necessary to uncheck the "Web" option on the first repair, and then do another repair with that option checked.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the installer once again and select the appropriate checkboxes for ASP.NET or Web development.I think you may not have selected that option when installing or it might have got missed.